# Materialize scrollspy with submenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, materialize, scrollspy

[Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) has a [scrollspy implementation](http://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html) for tables of contents, similar to [Bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy). This only issue is that it does not seem to support nested content – in other words, I have a table of contents right now that is an unordered list. I have sections in my markup so that the list elements highlight when they are in view:

```
<ul class="section table-of-contents">
  <li><a href="#pre-acquisition">Pre-acquisition</a></li>
  <li><a href="#accessioning">Accessioning</a></li>
  <li><a href="#post-acquisition">Post Acquisition</a></li>
  <li><a href="#templates">Templates for Acquisitions</a></li>
</ul>
```

and then the contents / sections in the page

```
<section id="pre-acquisition" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    content goes here
</section>
```

and so on. What I'd like to do is have nested sections like in Bootstrap's documentation menu. I've implemented this in my markup like so:

```
<ul class="section table-of-contents">
  <li><a href="#pre-acquisition">Pre-acquisition</a></li>
  <li><a href="#accessioning">Accessioning</a>
    <ul class="section table-of-contents submenu">
      <li><a href="#accessioning-guidelines">Guidelines</a></li>
      <li><a href="#accessioning-templates">Templates</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#post-acquisition">Post Acquisition</a></li>
  <li><a href="#templates">Templates for Acquisitions</a></li>
</ul>
```

With nested content sections like:

```
<section id="pre-acquisition" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    content
</section>

<section id="accessioning" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    content
<section id="accessioning-guidelines" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    more content
</section>
<section id="accessioning-templates" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    even more content
</section>
</section>
```

It is not highlighting my nested sections in the UL though. Is there a way to get this to work out of the box with Materialize? If not, how could I implement this with my own javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution – the HTML sections can not be nested.

So instead of:

```
<section id="pre-acquisition" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    content
</section>

<section id="accessioning" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    content
<section id="accessioning-guidelines" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    more content
</section>
<section id="accessioning-templates" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    even more content
</section>
</section>
```

One would do the following

```
<section id="pre-acquisition" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    content
</section>

<section id="accessioning" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    content
</section>
<section id="accessioning-guidelines" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    more content
</section>
<section id="accessioning-templates" class="section scrollspy" markdown="1">
    even more content
</section>
```

Semantically this is incorrect, as it does not bear a 1:1 correlation to the table of contents – but it works in the sense that the nested list elements do get highlighted.